# Find input id by indexRow

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```js
function getValue(elt) {
  index = elt.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  console.log(index)
  //display the id of input type="hidden"

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <dd id="calOp_id_1-element">
          <input name="calOp_id_1" value="1" id="calOp_id_1" type="hidden"></dd>
        <dd>
          <input name="calOp_date_debut_1" id="calOp_date_debut_1" value="02/04/2018" class="inlineBlock large  hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" style="width: 72px" readonly="readonly" type="text"></dd>
      </td>
      <td>
        <td>
          <dd id="calOp_1-element">
            <button name="calOp_1" id="calOp_1" type="button" onclick="getValue(this)">OK</button></dd>
        </td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want display the id of input type="hidden" (calOp_id_1) when I click the button OK

Comment: `onclick="javascript:getValue(this)"`

Comment: What do you mean *by the indexRow*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want display the id of input type="hidden" (calOp_id_1) when I click the button OK by the indexRow.

- I don't understand that, however, you can get that index using the attribute `rowIndex`.
- Use the function `closest` to get the parent element of the clicked button, in this case the current `tr`.

```js
function getValue(elt) {
  var tr = elt.closest('tr');
  console.log("index:", tr.rowIndex);
  var hidden = tr.querySelector('[type="hidden"]');
  var value = hidden.value;
  var id = hidden.id;
  console.log("Value:", value, "- Id:", id)
  //display the id of input type="hidden"
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <dd id="calOp_id_1-element">
          <input name="calOp_id_1" value="1" id="calOp_id_1" type="hidden"></dd>
        <dd>
          <input name="calOp_date_debut_1" id="calOp_date_debut_1" value="02/04/2018" class="inlineBlock large  hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" style="width: 72px" readonly="readonly" type="text"></dd>
      </td>
      <td>
        <td>
          <dd id="calOp_1-element">
            <button name="calOp_1" id="calOp_1" type="button" onclick="getValue(this)">OK#Index0</button></dd>
        </td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <dd id="calOp_id_2-element">
          <input name="calOp_id_2" value="1" id="calOp_id_2" type="hidden"></dd>
        <dd>
          <input name="calOp_date_debut_2" id="calOp_date_debut_2" value="02/04/2018" class="inlineBlock large  hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" style="width: 72px" readonly="readonly" type="text"></dd>
      </td>
      <td>
        <td>
          <dd id="calOp_2-element">
            <button name="calOp_2" id="calOp_2" type="button" onclick="getValue(this)">OK#Index1</button></dd>
        </td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have anothet question. I have the index number. How can I select the row by the index number

Comment: @fatma_wings you're welcome!.... `document.querySelector(seletor of table).rows[rowIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) combined with [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) :

- `.closest('tr')` finds the closest `tr` in the element's parents.
- `.querySelector('td:first-of-type>dd>input')` selects the input inside this table

```js
function getValue(e){
  console.log(e.closest('tr').querySelector('td:first-of-type>dd>input').id);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <dd id="calOp_id_1-element">
          <input name="calOp_id_1" value="1" id="calOp_id_1" type="hidden"></dd>
        <dd>
          <input name="calOp_date_debut_1" id="calOp_date_debut_1" value="02/04/2018" class="inlineBlock large  hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" style="width: 72px" readonly="readonly" type="text"></dd>
      </td>
      <td>
        <dd id="calOp_1-element">
          <button name="calOp_1" id="calOp_1" type="button" onclick="getValue(this)">OK</button></dd>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this looks like automated html output, the button with id "calOp_1" will be related to hidden element with id "calOp_id_1" and you could simply split to build the id and select it by id.

```js
function getValue(elt) {
  var name = elt.id.split("_");
  var hiddenID = name[0] + "_id_" + name[1];
  var hidden = document.getElementById(hiddenID);

  console.info(hiddenID + "=" + hidden.value);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <dd id="calOp_id_1-element">
          <input name="calOp_id_1" value="1" id="calOp_id_1" type="hidden"></dd>
        <dd>
          <input name="calOp_date_debut_1" id="calOp_date_debut_1" value="02/04/2018" class="inlineBlock large  hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" style="width: 72px" readonly="readonly" type="text"></dd>
      </td>
      <td>
        <td>
          <dd id="calOp_1-element">
            <button name="calOp_1" id="calOp_1" type="button" onclick="getValue(this)">OK</button></dd>
        </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your html , delete this : `onclick="getValue(this)"`

and on the js file , put this:

```
$("table button").click(function(){
       var val = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='hidden']").val();
       var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='hidden']").attr('id');
       console.log(val , id);
});
```

Comment: OP did not mention jQuery and you haven't explained that your answer uses jQuery.